# ML Kit on desktop

Tags: barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to integrate ML Kit/TFLite with java desktop applications, rather than having them run on an iOS/Android device?

I'd like to try out the barcode scanning capabilities on scanned documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of now, ML Kit is meant for mobile devices, and thus the iOS / Android focus. There is no desktop application support as of now. We would love the community to take this up as we love ML Kit to be used in as many ways as possible.

If it is just for prototyping something, the closest I can think of is firing up the mobile emulator on the desktop and use ML Kit.

Comment: You can try ML KIT android on raspberry pi.

Comment: @YasinBikmazer Why raspberry pi? Can you not run something in docker?

Comment: @mathtick I haven't been able to see an official docker distribution. If you're sure you've found a stable one, why not? Please share if possible.

Comment: @YasinBikmazer I think it might be something else of same name https://github.com/Munksgaard/mlkit-docker https://github.com/melsman/mlkit/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @mathtick Unfortunately it's not tensorflow library. The Google Tensorflow mentioned in the question and answer.